# Extract text from blurred rotated image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-tesseract

[image]

[image]

I have lots of image like these. Basically it's rotated and blur in nature. I just want to extract the table that contains **items, description and sale**. Can you please help me, how to extract that table from these type of image.

I have tried, but it's works for clear and non-rotated image.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(d), lang="eng")
print(text)
```

In our case, image might be rotated like 10, 20, 30, 40, or any angle.

Comment: If the letters are too blurred or too small, tesseract will not be able to read them.

Comment: For rotated images, I suggest you rotate them first.  There are also arguments to tesseract that you should read about for different geometries. And see https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md and https://muthu.co/all-tesseract-ocr-options/